# Iterating through an 2D array with python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to store points in an array, but I am not sure how to iterate thorugh it.

```
x = np.dot(weights, corners)
x_points = np.zeros([100, 2])
for i in range(101):
    x_points = (x + corners[np.random.randint(3)]) / 2
    x = x_points
```

I have tried to iterate my array like this:

```
x = np.dot(weights, corners)
x_points = np.zeros([100, 2])
for i in range(101):
    x_points[i:,] = (x + corners[np.random.randint(3)]) / 2
    x = x_points
```

How do i store each point in my array?

Comment: So `x` is a 100x2 array of points, and you want to average it with some random values from `corners`?

Comment: yes, I want to make new points. The new points are all inside a triangle. Its the algorithm for chaos game for the simplest case if you are familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You for loop is meant to iterate over your number of points, but you never specifically pick the i-th row from the original `x` array to work on; instead, you just use the entire array on every iteration. Here's what you should be doing:

```py
for i in range(101):
    x_points[i,:] = (x[i,:] + ...) / 2
```

(Note that you could even omit the second index if you wanted to: `x[i]` is the same as `x[i,:]`.)

In addition, you indexing for storing in the `x_points` array is wrong. I'm assuming you meant to write `x_points[i,:]` like I did above, instead of `x_points[i:,]`. The latter slices the array from the i-th row to the end along the first axis, so your code would actually modify more than just one row of `x_points` at a time.

Finally, I don't understand why you are assigning `x = x_points` on every loop iteration. This way, after the loop runs for the first time, your original `x` array doesn't exist anymore. If you want to "rename" the finalized `x_points`, you need to place this line after the for loop.

Comment: x = x_points replaces the old point with the new point, x[i+1] = x[i]+c[i] / 2. Should I also index corners?

Comment: I am trying with what you suggested:  x_points[i, :] = (x[i] + (corners[np.random.randint(3)])[i, :]) / 2,     but get error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.

Comment: Why `x[i+1]` now? Are you trying to replace points *below* the current row that you're operating on? You never mentioned that. I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As to your other error, you randomly grab one of the first three rows of `corners`, but why are you trying to index it again? Don't you just want to add that row to the current one from `x`?

Comment: I am giving up, my code gives the following error:  x_points[i, :] = (x + (corners[np.random.randint(3)])) / 2
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (2,)

Comment: I found out how to fix it another way :) Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Glad to hear. Maybe update your original post with your solution so others can benefit from it.

Comment: By the way, your broadcasting error was because `corners[...]` is a 1d array of length 2, and `x` is a 2d array of shape (100,2) and numpy couldn't automatically match these shapes. I think you might want to look into some general tutorials on numpy indexing and broadcasting so that this sort of issue will come more naturally to you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Numpy**

Assuming you have only 10 points to keep it readable here, I have shown how to create the arrays using Numpy, and accessing its elements.

```
>>> weights = np.random.randn(10,4)
>>> corners = np.random.rand(4,2)
>>> x=np.dot(weights, corners)
>>> x
array([[ 0.41183813,  0.18830351],
       [ 0.10599174,  0.76246711],
       [ 0.50235149,  2.76642114],
       [ 0.17072047,  0.67126034],
       [-0.25400796, -1.20589651],
       [-0.04360992, -0.06102023],
       [ 0.0446144 ,  0.48355716],
       [ 0.8501312 ,  1.93899732],
       [ 0.44656254,  1.05180096],
       [ 0.00397146,  0.19248246]])
>>> x_points = np.zeros([10, 2])
```

Now you have a set of x_points, initialized to 0.0, and your dot product of weights and corners in x.

```
for i in range(len(x_points)):
    x_points[i] = (x[i] + corners[np.random.randint(3)]) / 2
```

All your randomly initialized points, that took x values, and the corners into consideration have been written to x_points.

```
>>> x_points
array([[ 0.33206919,  0.25078735],
       [ 0.17914599,  0.53786916],
       [ 0.46472124,  1.74498146],
       [ 0.29890573,  0.69740106],
       [-0.08596056, -0.17476289],
       [ 0.01923846,  0.39767525],
       [ 0.14845732,  0.39841418],
       [ 0.46610902,  1.39768402],
       [ 0.43682676,  0.88767137],
       [ 0.04302915,  0.52442659]])
```

**For simple Python 2D arrays**

You create a 2D array as follows:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(num_cols)] for y in range(num_rows)]
```

Then, you access it like you would access a list with the index:

```
matrix[2][3] = 23

for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in len(num_cols):
        print(f"The element in the {i}th row, {j}th col is {matrix[i][j]}")
```

Comment: Is there another way that is more similar to my original code? I should also mention that corners is a vector that contains points.

Comment: Added a numpy based implementation. Tip: when your dimensions  while using numpy, you can directly access every outer element as if it were a regular array.